# Configure SharePoint People Search to Exclude Users Without Photos

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

I am working with SharePoint 2013 People search and I need to be able to exclude accounts without pictures (which are all system\admin accounts) from the People Search Results.  Has anyone else ever done this and if so then please provide guidance and configuration\code examples.

Thanks!

Tom

Comment: Again Tom, you should look at creating this filter in the UPSA rather than filtering the crawl. You can flag your service accounts in AD and then filter on that flag in the Import.

Answer (score 1):

You could create one user property for the users to flag the users without photo.

Then create managed property for the user property in search service application.

Then you can create custom result resource for the people result, and exclude the users with the flag property by property filter.

Then in search result web part, you can choose the custom people result resource.

Comment: If the reply is helpful to you, you could mark the reply as answer. Thanks for your understanding.